# Manually Group Barplot By Index

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot where there are 4 groups (bars 1 + 2, bars 3 + 4, etc), but there's no indication of this in the dataset. How can I manually add space, add a shared group label (x-axis) and recolour the 4 groups?

[image]

Data (melted):

[image]

Curent Ggplot code:

```
xdr<-melt(result)

ggplot(
  aes(x = variable, y = value), data = xdr) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom = "bar") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0.6,0.85)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "bar") + 
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom = "errorbar")
```

Comment: "there's no indication of this in the dataset": can you add one? You know what the groups are. Once you have the grouping recorded in your data it becomes much easier to represent that grouping in a plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll want to use `mutate()` to add the groups, in whatever way is appropriate for your data, and then `facet_wrap()` to make the kind of subgraphs you are talking about.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~variable, ~value,
  "baseline1", 0.730,
  "baseline2", 0.521,
  "baseline3", 0.762,
  "baseline4", 0.655,  
  "baseline5", 0.604,  
  "baseline6", 0.710,  
  "baseline7", 0.528,  
  "baseline8", 0.172
)

df %>%
  mutate(group = (row_number() + 1) %/% 2,
         group = paste("Group", group)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(variable, value, fill = group)) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~group, nrow = 1, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]